# How to determine if two $6 \times 6$ nilpotent matrices are similar?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, nilpotence

Let $A$ and $B$ be two $6 \times6$ nilpotent matrices. How would you prove they are similar?

By definition, their characteristic polynomials are equal, being $\lambda^6$, but from there how can I proceed?

Comment: The invariant factors must be the same. Can you list all the possible Jordan form with the given characteristic polynomial?

Comment: In general, two $n\times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ over an algebraically closed field $F$ are similar if and only if $\operatorname{rank}\left((\lambda I-A)^k\right)=\operatorname{rank}\left((\lambda I-B)^k\right)$ for every $\lambda\in F$ and every $k=1,2,\ldots,n$. Since your $A,B$ are known to be nilpotent, it suffices to consider only $\lambda=0$.

Comment: Is there a unique and sufficient condition based on the blocks? These two matrices have blocks of different sizes... Computing the powers for these two matrices is too tedious to even consider. @user1551

Comment: @DMan Six-by-six matrices are rather small by today's standard. Any popular computer algebra system (Matlab, Mathematica, SymPy, Sage, Maxima, etc.) shall be able to cope with them easily.